# Custom extension on Compose.IO PostgreSQL cluster

Tags: postgresql, compose-db

The [Compose.IO postgresql documentation](https://help.compose.com/docs/postgresql-faq#section-how-do-i-add-an-extension) describes how to install an extension from a list of available extensions.

I would like to install the [decoderbufs extension](https://github.com/debezium/postgres-decoderbufs), but this extension is not in the list of available extensions.  Is it possible to install an extension that is not in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some feedback from support:

> It's not possible to install custom extensions, but we can take
>   on-board this extension as a suggestion for future inclusion.